# nodelet xml file not installed

Tags: ros-groovy, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a CMakeLists.txt to compile pointcloud_to_laserscan for groovy.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
project(pointcloud_to_laserscan)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
            roscpp  nodelet sensor_msgs pcl_ros
             dynamic_reconfigure)
# PCL (do NOT use 1.7)
find_package(PCL 1.6 EXACT REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})             
             
#generate cfg 
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/CloudScan.cfg)
# Use this to define what the package will export (e.g. libs, headers).
catkin_package(
#   INCLUDE_DIRS include
#   LIBRARIES pointcloud_to_laserscan
   LIBRARIES cloud_to_scan
   CATKIN_DEPENDS nodelet roscpp pluginlib)

##############################################################################
# Binaries
##############################################################################
add_library(cloud_to_scan
            src/cloud_to_scan.cpp src/cloud_throttle.cpp
            )
target_link_libraries(cloud_to_scan 
                      ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} )
install(TARGETS cloud_to_scan
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    )
```

I installed it with this command

```
catkin_make_isolated --pkg pointcloud_to_laserscan -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=true --install  --install-space /opt/ros/groovy
```

When I use the associated launch file, the following message appears:

```
   [ERROR] [1411833572.330693140]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/groovy/share/pointcloud_to_laserscan/nodelets.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
```

Does it mean that I have to copy the file ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193627/nodelet-xml-file-not-installed/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2014-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to explicitly specify which files should be installed in your `CMakeLists.txt` file (assuming the file specifying your nodelet is calles `nodelets.xml` and is beside the `CMakeLists.txt` file):

```
install(
  FILES nodelets.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2014-09-28**:
perfect. I thought it was handled somewhere by catkin, like `package.xml`